# Why for 10-fold cross validations Weka runs learning algorithm 11 times?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, cross-validation

I am currently working on WEKA , and just want to know why in cross validation using 10 fold cross validation, learning algorithm runs 11 time

Comment: buest guess is that it refits on the whole dataset afterwards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167287/cross-validation-weka-api/19167712#19167712  I believe lejlot's answer is correct, the reasoning in the referenced question explains why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weka first builds a model on the entire dataset (if you right click on the experiment you can save this), and then performs the 10-fold cross-validation.